# Castle Windsor Install Multiple Instance Service By Convention From Object

Tags: castle-windsor

After doing some reading it seems that passing raw data types into constructors is not the best way to handle the constructor injection (not sure that this is true or not but ok ill buy it).
So Needing some info from the user (entered on the command prompt) I am doing the following.

NOTE: just an example but is conceptually the same

```
public interface IArg
{
    string Value{get;set;}
}

public interface IServerNameArg : IArg{}

public class ServerName : IServerNameArg
{
    public string Value{get;set;}
}

public interface ISomethingElseArg:IArg{}

public class SomethingElseArg : ISomethingElseArg
{
    public string Value{get;set;}
}


public interface ICommandArgs
{
    IServerNameArg{get;set;}
    ISomethingElseArg{get;set;]
}
```

So for a previous project I did something similar but did not have an interface for each setting and just passed the entire object around wherever these settings were needed.
Not horrible but I can see some value in wanting to only pass the relevant arguments.

```
container.Register(Componenet
    .For<IArgs>()
    .Instance(args)
```

So my first question (if i am approaching this issue properly) is can i do a similar .Instance install using convention and have each property of my ICommandArgs and install as an Instance service?
Not sure what it would look like but something like

```
container.Register(Classes
    .From(typeof(ICommandArgs))
    .BasedOn<IArg>()
    .WithServiceBase());
```

I know I can install each property individually but i am looking to be able to add args in the future and have them get wired up not having to remember to install them too.
One other approach I was tinkering with was to use linq and reflection to get all the properties of type IArg from my instance of ICommandArgs then install each one as an instance.

Am i going too far?
Should i just be dependant on the ICommandArgs and install an instance service there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so reflection it is. using code below i am pulling all the properties from the instance of "args"

```
        //get all properties from args class that implement IVar so they can be registered automatically  
        var argsToRegister = _args.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x =>
                    x.GetValue(_args) != null
                    && x.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IVar)))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Name,
                    Type = x.PropertyType,
                    Value = x.GetValue(_args)
                }).ToList();
```

Then I register each one as an instance for all interfaces (this is specific to my solution and you should be mindful of what you are registering)

```
        //register each IVar from the args instance as instance vars
        foreach (var arg in argsToRegister)
        {
            var types = arg.Type.GetInterfaces().ToList();
            types.Add(arg.Type);

            container.Register(Component
                .For(types)
                .Instance(arg.Value)
                .IsDefault()
               );
        }
```

I then go and register all of my other IVars that have not already been registered

```
        //register all IVar that are not contained as properties in the args implementation 
        container.Register(Classes
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IVar>()
            .If(t=> !argsToRegister.Any(a=>a.Type.IsAssignableFrom(t)))
            .WithServiceBase()
        );
```